# Basic HTML White square header Bug Homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, shopify

I build by research and copy+paste this fixed Headertitle but unfortunately I have a problem after I load the side and scroll up there is a white space where the title jumps into and than back. Can anyone help me removing this Bug?

Its super annoying...and I tried almost everything to remove it.

I want it that my Title is fixed at one point and stays there in the top layer thats why I also put zindex -999

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Impact;z-index: 999;
}

.top-container {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: #transparent;
  color: #transparent;
  z-index: 999;
}

.header {
  position: auto;
  padding: auto, auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #transparent;
  color: #transparent;
  z-index: 999;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 999;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
    <h2><center>97cm</center></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: side note: `window.onscroll = myFunction;` will do

Comment: why are you using javascript to add the `.sticky` class when you scroll - why not just add that class to the div anyway?

Comment: @MacroMan sorry I am absolutely new to this, what do I have to remove or add now?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your sticky class and get rid of the javascript

```
<div class="header sticky" id="myHeader">
```

---

**Explanation:**

Your sticky class is set up to "stick" the div to the top of the page, but you don't actually assign this class to your `<div>`.

Then you have some javascript that checks if you've scrolled down the page and *then* assigns the `.sticky` class to your `<div>`

The white space and "jump" that you're seeing is the delay between you scrolling, and the javascript applying the `.sticky` class. You always want this `</div>` to be sticky, so just have the `sticky` class permanently assigned to it, and remove all the javascript.

Comment: so i remove this part? function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>

Comment: the javascript.... yes. Remove that and add the `sticky` to the `class=` part as I've posted above...

Comment: perfect! that works!! but I still need to put some space on top because if I go on Mobile version im not able to click on the Menu Bar anymore...

Comment: That's a different question, I'd suggest you look at CSS and media queries - it's too broad for a question on here.

Comment: thank you for your help. Is it that difficult to lower the Title down? I barely know that I have to add somewhere padding or change the position but I don't wanna destroy the whole code again -.- Would help so much!